# WooCommerce - Hide an attribute for a specific variable

Tags: wordpress, variables, woocommerce, attributes

I have a wood product I am selling that comes in two main attributes, Pine and Hardwood.

If they choose Pine I want to give them the option to choose a finish for the top and a finish for the bottom (two separate attributes). But if they choose the hardwood option then I don't want to options for different finishes to be selectable. I'm having a hell of a time figuring out how to get this accomplished and I've been searching solutions for the last 3 hours.

In short, these are the attributes I am offering:

Wood type: Pine - Hardwood
Top Finish (Pine only): 8 options to choose from
Leg Finish (Pine only): 8 options to choose from
Height (Pine and Hardwood): 4 options to choose from

Comment: change product type to variable. set options that you want.

Comment: That's how you get the options for attributes and variables in the first place, so obviously I've already done that. But that doesn't help answer my question at all.